# How to use a public class Reports (for logging purpose) with public static methods across other classes of the same project

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Here's an excerpt of my prorgam:

```
package something.util;
public class Reports {
    public static void logStatus(LogStatus testStatus, String testDetails) {
        test.log(testStatus, testDetails);
    }
}

package something.pages;
public class MainPage {
    public void someMethod(){
        Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Clicked A/B Testing link");
    }
}
```

When I execute the code above, I keep getting NullPointerException and I am not sure why. At least a pointer to the mistake I'm making will help.

Comment: Post your exception message. It should tell you exactly where the error is coming from. From there, you need to investigate why that variable is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` object, in the Reports class, will be null in the following line.

```
test.log(testStatus, testDetails);
```

Thats why its giving NPE.

Comment: Oh. That's great. Your solution worked. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Dont call `log` method directly on test

```
test.log(testStatus, testDetails)
```

you can call like this, as this is static method,

```
MainPage.log(testStatus, testDetails)
```

or this will work too,

```
MainPage test = new MainPage();
test.log(testStatus, testDetails)
```